# Join on multiple tables using mysql and many foreign keys

Tags: mysql, join

Using MySQL, I have 3 tables as follows:

```
locations (id, name)
products(id, description)
inventory_records(id, product_id, move_from, move_to)
```

`product_id` is a FK to **products**; `move_from` and `move_to` are FK to **locations**.

The following query lists all products names and their origins.

```
select
    products.description,
    locations.name
from
    inventory_records
inner join products on
    products.id = inventory_records.product_id
inner join locations on
    locations.id = inventory_records.move_from    
limit 10;
```

But I wanna list both origin and destinations, which I couldn't compose the query. Any helps?

Comment: Add another `JOIN` between `locations.id = inventory_records.move_to`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to Join the `locations` table twice. First Join will be on `move_from`; and second table join would be on `move_to`.

Also, note that it is a good practice to use [Aliasing](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-alias/) in case of multi-table queries, for code clarity, readability and unambiguous behavior.

```
SELECT
    products.description,
    lfrom.name AS move_from_location, 
    lto.name AS move_to_location 
FROM
    inventory_records
INNER JOIN products ON
    products.id = inventory_records.product_id
INNER JOIN locations AS lfrom ON
    lfrom.id = inventory_records.move_from    
INNER JOIN locations AS lto ON
    lto.id = inventory_records.move_to  
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: That worked!! Thanks. I will look into this syntax to build the more complicated queries I need.